# ng-bootstrap ,on click, change dropdown icon

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

on click, change to icon:- fa-angle-down.

By default, I am showing fa-angle-up, on click it should change to fa-angle-down.

```
<div class="col text-right">
    <div ngbDropdown placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
      <div  id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x"></i> <!--show me on click-->
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic2">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use template variable to get isOpen method that return boolean value use the that value and bind class accordingly

```
<div class="col text-right">
        <div  #myDrop="ngbDropdown" ngbDropdown placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
          <div  id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle>
            <i [ngClass] ="Mydrop.isOpen() ==true ? 'fa fa-angle-up ' : ''fa fa-angle-down' "></i>
          </div>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic2">
            <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: not changing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6clph9?file=app/dropdown-basic.html